# Python are if elif codes the most efficient way of solving this issue?

Tags: python

I'm still learning to code and I'm wondering if there's a way of getting the same results from my code without using all the if and elif statements, it seems really inefficient.

Is there some way I could use the list 'finishList' to check if the values match? or is the if elif statements the best option for me?

Code is below.

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.finishList = ['ABUL','BEL','PBL','PBUL','ABL','SBL','SBSL','SBUL','PNP','SNP','PCP','SCP','NBP','ASP','ACP','SAL','SAS','AMB','CBP','HBN','MBL','MWL','HBB','SPE','PBUL/SAMPLE']#list to append to techcodelist
        mergedList = (['tc1', 'yes', 'no', 'no'], ['tc2', 'no', 'no', 'no'], ['tc3', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no'], ['tc3', 'yes', 'yes', 'y'], ['tc1/test', 'no', 'n', 'yes'], ['tc1/test/testier', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'])
        leadList = list()

        for i, item in enumerate(mergedList):
                for x, item in enumerate(self.finishList):
                    leadTime = int(2)
                    if self.finishList[x] == 'ABL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 3
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'ABUL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'ACP':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 4
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'AMB':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 3
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'ASP':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 9#originally 4 but includes 5 extra days as sent out
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'BEL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'CBP':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 4
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'HBB':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 1
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'HBN':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'MBL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 6#originally 1 but includes 5 extra days as sent out
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'MWL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 7#originally 2 but includes 5 extra days as sent out
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'NBP':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'PBL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'PBUL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 1
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'PCP':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'PNP':
                        leadTime - leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'SAL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 3
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'SAS':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 3
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'SBL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'SBSL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'SBUL':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 1
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'SCP':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2
                    elif self.finishList[x] == 'SNP':
                        leadTime = leadTime + 2

                    if mergedList[i][1] == 'y' or mergedList[i][1] == 'yes':
                        leadTime = leadTime+1
                    if mergedList[i][2] == 'y' or mergedList[i][2] == 'yes':
                        leadTime = leadTime+1
                    if mergedList[i][3] == 'y' or mergedList[i][3] == 'yes':
                        leadTime = leadTime+1

                    leadTime = str(leadTime)
                    leadList.append(leadTime)

myClass()
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you can use a dictionary and then do `leadTime += my_dict[self.finishList[x]]`.

Comment: notice that you also have `elif self.finishList[x] == 'PNP':leadTime - leadTime + 2` which is i think not what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to look up the increment that corresponds to the value of `self.finishList[x]`:

```
mapping = {'ABL': 3,
           ...,
           'SNP': 2}

increment = mapping.get(self.finishList[x])
leadTime = leadTime + increment
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the finishList as a dictionary with the key being the current value in the list, and the number to add being the value.

```
self.finishedList = { "ABUL":2, ... }
```

Then, you can iterate through the dictionary using `for key in self.finishList:` and add to leadTime: `leadTime += self.finishedList[key]`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in a dictionary with the key being the string characters and the days added being the values. Example below.

```
leadTime += values_dic[self.finishList[x]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had input data that had different strings from `finishList`, you could use a dictionary that mapped the strings to the different values, but this is not actually needed here because you only ever use those strings in a loop that iterates over the entire list in the same order each time -- hence you could get the same exact `leadTime` values by just putting those values directly in a list and skipping the strings entirely.  The same goes for the `mergedList` values, since all you ever care about is the number of `yes` entries in each list; you *could* compute that value more easily with a loop that sums them up, but it's easier to just sum it up ahead of time and have that be the thing you iterate over.

The following code will therefore produce the exact same `leadList` end result as your original code, with significantly less time and effort:

```
finish_list = [
    4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 11, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 2
]
merged_list = [
    1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2
]
leadList = [
    str(finish + merged) 
    for merged in merged_list 
    for finish in finish_list
]
```

Comment: Hi, finishList and mergedList are relevant in other parts of the larger project hence why they're being used here. This is just the minimum amount required to produce the results I'm after with the lead time list. Thanks.